# Dot Notation Prepared Statement MS SQL JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

Using Prepared Statements via MSSQL JDBC:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmp? ( ot smalldatetime, value smallint );
CREATE TABLE ##tmp? ( ot smalldatetime, value smallint );
```

works!

```
INSERT INTO ##tmp?
SELECT Forecast_Valid_Time, Temperature
FROM fct_masterAll
WHERE Location_ID = ? AND
      revision = 0 AND 
      forecast_type_code = 4 AND 
      forecaster = 'ETA' AND
      Forecast_Issued_Time = ?
ORDER BY Forecast_Valid_Time ASC;
```

works!

```
INSERT INTO ##tmp?
SELECT Forecast_Valid_Time, Temperature
FROM fct_masterAll
WHERE Location_ID = ? AND
      revision = 0 AND 
      forecast_type_code = 4 AND 
      forecaster = 'MRF' AND
      Forecast_Issued_Time = ?
ORDER BY Forecast_Valid_Time ASC;
```

works!

but...

```
SELECT ##tmp?.ot, ( ##tmp?.value + ##tmp?.value ) FROM ##tmp?, ##tmp?;

Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name '##tmp@P3'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
```

There seems to be a problem with the 'dot notation' in the SELECT statement above.  I can successfully execute a:

```
SELECT * FROM ##tmp?;
```

Passing in the parameter.

Is the problem with the dot-notation, or with the join?

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Shouldn't `FROM ##tmp?, ##tmp?` be just `FROM ##tmp?`? You could also try surrounding the table name with double quotes.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks so much for the quick response! When you pass in the 'parameters', the SELECT statement is actually:  SELECT ##tmp0.ot, ( ##tmp0.value + ##tmp1.value ) FROM ##tmp0, ##tmp1;

Comment: A-ha, didn't first understand that you were trying to pass a parameter there. You cannot use bind variables like that -- you can only parameterize column _values_, not column/table names. The SQL that holds the placeholders (`?`) has to be valid and parseable to the DB without the values so that execution plans etc. can be calculated beforehand.

Comment: I don't see how your first examples can work, actually, unless you have a table named `##tmp?`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic  Thanks so much!  Everything works until you get to said SELECT statement.  I can pass parameters into a SELECT * FROM ##tmp? and get a result set.  It's when I try to do the join using the dot notation where it starts complaining.  Unless something else comes up...I'll need to find a different approach.   Again, thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aliasing?

```
SELECT A.ot, ( A.value + B.value ) FROM ##tmp? A, ##tmp? B;
```

That way you'd remove the variable reference from your select while still keeping them for the actual selection of tables.

(Guesswork. Might work, might fail, might make me look silly :-)

Comment: @Jan...Thanks so much for the response!  Your solution got me a little closer, but it still didn't work.  Your solution made the parser much happier.  I was able to execute the code without error...however...there was no (an empty) result set.   The query works when I execute it from plain SQL (i.e. no prepared statements).  I've since had to move on to another approach.